# While Batch Inserting to Mongodb WriteConcern detected an error 'E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am creating a `List<MyCollectionItem>` 
and use insertbatch method to insert the list. (`_collection.InsertBatch(entities)`)

I do not set an id to MyCollectionItem object.
And I expect mongo to set the id.

It throws the exception 
**Unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**
and when I look at the write concern I see this error **WriteConcern detected an error 'E11000 duplicate key error index:**

but the items count that i send to method and the inserted items in db are same...
seems it successfully inserted all the data...

How can i fix this? Where should I check?

the index info is here...

```
{MongoDB.Driver.IndexInfo}
DroppedDups: false
IsBackground: false
IsSparse: false
IsUnique: false
Key: { "_id" : 1 }
Name: "_id_"
Namespace: "MyDB.MyCollection"
RawDocument: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "MyDB.MyCollection", "name" : "_id_" }
TimeToLive: {10675199.02:48:05.4775807}
Version: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which is fixed with the updates of the driver. If you see this error 
**update your driver to the latest version**.

you may want to check these jira issues for more information.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-715

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-725